# AWS iOT login issue using IAM user credentials iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am trying to login into the AWS iOT using the IAM user credentials.
But I am getting the error continuously "connection error", in the console it is showing as "CP Conn 0x2819e8a80 SSLHandshake failed (-9807)". I checked with different wifi connections but still, I am getting the same errors.

Here I am sharing my code to get the more clarity,

```
        let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: myAccessKey, secretKey: mySecretKey)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

        AWSIoTDataManager.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "iOTManager")
        iotDataManager = AWSIoTDataManager(forKey: "iOTManager")

        #if DEMONSTRATE_LAST_WILL_AND_TESTAMENT
        let lwtTopic: NSString = Constants.lwtTopic
        let lwtMessage: NSString = Constants.lwtMessage
        self.iotDataManager.mqttConfiguration.lastWillAndTestament.topic = lwtTopic as String
        self.iotDataManager.mqttConfiguration.lastWillAndTestament.message = lwtMessage as String
        self.iotDataManager.mqttConfiguration.lastWillAndTestament.qos = .AtMostOnce
        #endif

        self.iotDataManager.connectUsingWebSocket( withClientId: UUID().uuidString, cleanSession:true, statusCallback: mqttEventCallback)
    }

    func mqttEventCallback( _ status: AWSIoTMQTTStatus ) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(status.rawValue)
            switch(status)
            {
            case .connecting:
                print("Connecting..!")

            case .connected:
                print("Connected..!")

            case .disconnected:
                print("Disconnected..!")

            case .connectionRefused:
                print("connectionRefused..!")

            case .connectionError:
                print("connectionError..!")

            case .protocolError:
                print("protocolError..!")

            default:
                print("unknowState" + String(status.rawValue))
            }
        }
```

When I am running the same code in iPad mini, I am able to login into AWS iOT successfully but it is not in iPhone(7, 7Plus, 8Plus). I was wondering, why it is happening. I am not getting what wrong in the code. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you get solution of it ?

Comment: Not Yet, Please help me

Comment: This is an issue since iOS 12.1.1 because of the deprecation of trust of Symantec CAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found this 2 things

1) SSL handshake fail when using new endpoint with '-ats' or '.ats'  [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/issues/248)

2) Its gives issue in higher version (IOS 12.1.1) so check your device version.

Please refer this [Doc](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/pubsub) also